# How to count whitespace occurences in a string in c++

Tags: c++, string, file-io

I have a project for my advanced c++ class that's supposed to do a number of things, but I'm trying to focus on this function first, because after it works I can tweak it to fulfill the other needs. This function searches through a file and performs a word count by counting the number of times ' ' appears in the document. Maybe not accurate, but it'll be a good starting place. Here's the code I have right now:

```
void WordCount()
    {
        int count_W = 0; //Varaible to store word count, will be written to label
        int i, c = 0; //i for iterator
        ifstream fPath("F:\Project_1_Text.txt");
        FileStream input( "F:\Project_1_Text.txt", FileMode::Open, FileAccess::Read );

        StreamReader fileReader( %input );
        String ^ line;
        //char ws = ' ';
        array<Char>^ temp;

        input.Seek( 0, SeekOrigin::Begin );

        while ( ( line = fileReader.ReadLine() ) != nullptr )
            {
                Console::WriteLine( line );
                c = line->Length;
                //temp = line->ToCharArray();

                for ( i = 0; i <= c; i++)
                {
                    if ( line[i] == ' '  )
                            count_W++;
                }

                //line->ToString();
            }

        //Code to write to label
        lblWordCount->Text = count_W.ToString();
    }
```

All of this works except for one problem. When I try to run the program, and open the file, I get an error that tells me the Index is out of bounds. Now, I know what that means, but I don't get how the problem is occurring. And, if I don't know what's causing the problem, I can't fix it. I've read that it is possible to search through a string with a for loop, and of course that also holds true for a char array, and there is code in there to perform that conversion, but in both cases I get the same error. I know it is reading through the file correctly, because the final program also has to perform a character count (which is working), and it read back the size of each line in the target document perfectly from start to finish. Anyway, I'm out of ideas, so I thought I'd consult a higher power. Any ideas?

Comment: Backslashes inside string literals need to be doubled.

Comment: `String ^ line;`? Is this an MS-specific variant of C++? If so, mention that in the tags.

Comment: @j_random_hacke: looks like managed c++ to me. but yeah you're right...@Robert Berry: Please tag it.

Comment: If you get an index out of bounds error, the best thing to do is to A. determine what line and what index it is, and then ask your self the following question, "Why is this index out of bounds in this string" and how can I fix my code so it doesn't do that. and what is the range of valid indexes for this line. I suggest reading the documentation for String

Answer (score 3):

Counting whitespace is simple:

```
int spaces = std::count_if(s.begin(), s.end(),
                           [](unsigned char c){ return std::isspace(c); });
```

Two notes, though:

1. `std::isspace()` cannot be used immediately with `char` because `char` may be signed and `std::isspace()` takes an `int` which is required to be positive.
2. This counts the number of spaces, not the number of words (or words - 1): words may be separated by sequences of spaces consisting of more than one consecutive space.

Comment: @user13107: the `[]` introduces a lambda function (one with an empty closure). The whole purpose of this function is to call `std::isspace()` with `int`s correctly converted from `char`.

Answer (score 1):

It could be your loop. You're going from i=0 to i=c, but i=c is too far. You should go to i=c-1:

```
for ( i=0; i<c; i++)
```

Comment: That one change got the word count working. Thank you so much